# Colors in C terminal (Windows)

Tags: c, colors, terminal

So, I'm making a program where the user will be able to play solitaire on the terminal, however I would like so that the terminal displays different colors for each "card". Maybe something along the lines of:

```
printf("%c - %c", (red)ten_clubs, (white)ace_spades);
```

I already looked up some answers to this problem, however they deal with it using solutions that only work on UNIX, and I'm currently developing using Dev-C++ on Windows.

I really don't know how I would make something along these lines, so if anyone can help me I would be really grateful

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 ways to do it.

Either you use [pdcurses](https://pdcurses.sourceforge.io/) which makes it a bit portable if you plan on moving your code to Unices.

OR

You can use [Win32 Console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) which takes a bit of learning to get it going. Something like:

```
HANDLE  h_stdout;

h_stdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

SetConsoleTextAttribute(h_stdout, FOREGROUND_RED);
printf("%c", ten_cubs);
SetConsoleTextAttribute(h_stdout, FOREGROUND_WHITE);
printf("%c" ace_spades);
```

This should give you an idea.